# Is there a way to send Cloud Messages or Push Notifications to a Flutter App from C#?

Tags: c#, flutter, winforms, push-notification

For my use case, a user from C# WinForm desktop application generates some data (creates a new document in a collection named "Requests" in Firestore). What I want is that whenever a new document is created/added in the Requests collection, a notification is sent to the Flutter app. I am looking for some guidelines for a workaround regarding this using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have already connected your C# software with firebase as backend. If that is the case then:

**1-** First connect your flutter app to firebase.
Follow this link to do so: [Connect flutter app to firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/)

**2-** Use this link to learn and **create your first cloud function on firebase.**
[Create first cloud function from flutter app terminal](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

**3-** Now you are in the position to create a cloud function with which a notification will be generated to the device you want **on the creation of document in the request collection.**

**4-** ***Deploy this function*** on your firebase to send notification to your required device.

```
exports.sendFirstNotification =
  functions.firestore.document('/Requests/{documentId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
var name = "Bilal Saeed";

  var myDeviceToken = snap.data().fcmToken;
// You need this token for push notification on a device.
// Each device has its own token.
// Access it in this function. 
//If you are working on C# software then create your token from flutter app
 //and save it on firestore. And access that token here and save it in myDeviceToken variable.
// Currently in this function its assumed that, the newly document created //in your Request collection contains the device token which is being //assigned to myDeviceToken variable.

  await admin.messaging().send({
    token: myDeviceToken,
    notification: {
         title: `Hi, you received first notification by the help of ${name}`,
         body: " Upvote his answer if he really helped you!"
        },
    
  }).then(value => {
    functions.logger.log("First notification sent to the device");
  }).catch((e) =>{
    functions.logger.log(e.toString());
  });
});
```

Use this **command from terminal to deploy your** this **function.**

```
firebase deploy --only functions:sendFirstNotification
```

*Now create the document from your C# software and you will get the notification on your flutter app mobile device on the creation of document in Requests Collection. Congrats!*